# Python telebot Нужно заменить пробелы символами

Tags: python, парсер, telebot, beautiful-soup

Паршу каталог товаров с сайта в бота телеграм (Beautifulsoup4)
При вводе боту названия товара - он мне отправляет список товаров на странице, который получил при подстановке в ссылку site/search?search=[текст от пользователя]
Проблема в том, что нужно вводить 2 и более слова, но пробелы нужно заменять символами "%20"

Пример: site/search?search=лампа%20накаливания

Вообще нет идей как это можно сделать(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К примеру так:

`str='site/search?search=лампа накаливания'  str=str.replase(' ', '%20')`

Comment: Краткость - сестра таланта